# How to make Payment Gateway in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento2, payment

Please provide any official documents or any demo/tutorials mode for this (How to make Payment Gateway in Magento 2).

I was referring to http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/ but no success yet.

Comment: Any Updates At least Provide any official doc from magento side?

Comment: What kind of Payment Gateway you want? Credit Card based? Third party redirection based? or just the payment method as a name(offline)?

Comment: I want to make both Third party redirection based  or also Credit Card form based

Comment: using Adapter Class, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-custom-payment-method-using-adapter-class-magento-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the URL of a module creator. I hope this will help you.

https://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/payment-module

Comment: After making zip by this creater and integrate in magento 2 after that clear cache there is no effect not shown in admin panel or not in frontend please suggest

Comment: 1 thing cross check in etc/config your module entry i there or not if not then may be register,php i mised add that fine  2nd point if entry is there then it mean module i installed (to intall module run bin\magento setup:upgrade) and then run bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy to move need js to pub/static folder

Comment: After doing all this there is no reflection i am checked apache error log there is not any error please tell me how to check magento 2 error log?

Comment: That link is not available. Could you fix this?

Comment: @PradeepKumar - The above link is dead. This is the main reason why we should not post link only answers.

Comment: url not longer exist

Answer (score 2):

In order to create Payment integration, it is expected to follow and use API which is located in the `Magento/Payment` module. There is a Gateway API inside the module which has interfaces and some common implementations.

By using this API, you might be able to implement Remote or Direct Payment integration. In addition to this API, there is a set of UI elements which have to be used to show your custom Payment method under Checkout payment step.

You may also want to check examples and detailed explanation on how to use Payment Gateway API in the [Magento 2 Payment Gateway API](http://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-payment-gateway-api) article. Also, please have a look on how to properly configure Payment Method adapter class in the [Magento 2 Payment Gateway Configuration](http://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-payment-adapter-configuration).

Please do not hesitate to contact me or leave a comment with any questions related to Payment implementations.

Comment: :-  this will helps to call api call internally if we need to redirect to other website that is payment gate way website then how to do it , in m1 we use getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() in M2 its not working , then how to do it in m2

Comment: i got it to redirect payment gateway website url follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416686/magento-2-no-redirect-to-external-payment-provder

Comment: Hi Max pronko, At this time i am stuck in making parameter in magento 2 admin panel i want a dropdown list in magento 2 admin panel in our payment gateway section can you help me ?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94297/how-to-add-backend-parameter-for-select-box-in-magento-2

Comment: how to Get redirected to our payment gateway page in magento 2?